# Function ‘array’ has no IMPLICIT type

Tags: function, compiler-errors, fortran

Here is my Fortran 90 code:

```
program test
implicit none

integer*4 nxProjPad, cf, numViews, cc, index, indRad, iv, i
real*4 v4, v5, SS
nxProjPad=185
numViews=180
v4 = 0.
v5 = 0.
SS = 0.

cf = NINT(nxProjPad/2.)

do  iv = 1, numViews

do i = 1, nxProjPad

v4 = v4 + array(index)

v5 = v5 + array(indRad)
SS = SS + ABS(array(index))

indRad = indRad + 1

index = index + 1

enddo

enddo


end
```

and I always get the errors:

```
test.f90:19:15:

 v4 = v4 + array(index)
               1
Error: Function ‘array’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
test.f90:21:15:

 v5 = v5 + array(indRad)
               1
Error: Function ‘array’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
test.f90:23:14:

 SS = SS + ABS(array(index))
              1
Error: Function ‘array’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

I have searched and have seen similar answers but still could not figure my problem. Any suggestion is welcome and thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you think `array` is ?  The compiler thinks it's a function that you haven't provided a definition for.  I can't see any declaration of any thing called `array`.

Comment: Use tag `fortran` for your Fortran questions You can add a specific version where necessary (not here).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be that `array` is simply not declared. It doesn't have an implicit type, because you have wisely chosen to disable implicit typing with `IMPLICIT NONE`.

There are two possible things an item which is called with `array(<int>)` could be: It could be an array or a function. The compiler, not being able to make proper conclusions, suspects that you might have somewhere wanted to declare a function:

```
function array(i)
    implicit none
    integer :: i
    <some type> :: array
    <some code that calculates array>
end function array
```

But because it has not found any code of that sort, it tells you that you haven't implemented it yet, and you haven't declared it either.

What I suspect, because I understand not only Fortran but also to some extend English, is that it's more likely meant to be an array of type `REAL*4`.

So try this:

```
program test
    implicit none

    integer*4 nxProjPad, cf, numViews, cc, index, indRad, iv, i 
    real*4 v4, v5, SS

    ! Create an allocatable array (allocatable, because we only know
    ! the size once nxProjPad and numViews have been set.)
    real*4, dimension(:), allocatable :: array

    nxProjPad=185
    numViews=180

    ! both indRad and index get incremented for each
    ! iteration of either loop, so the maximum array index
    ! is the product of numViews and nxProjPad
    allocate(array(numViews*nxProjPad))

    v4 = 0.
    v5 = 0.
    SS = 0.

    ! These weren't originally initialised before their first use.
    ! Correct that
    indRad = 1
    index = 1

    cf = NINT(nxProjPad/2.)

    do  iv = 1, numViews
        do i = 1, nxProjPad
            v4 = v4 + array(index)

            v5 = v5 + array(indRad)
            SS = SS + ABS(array(index))

            indRad = indRad + 1

            index = index + 1
        enddo
    enddo

    ! Properly deallocate the array again
    deallocate(array)
end program test
```

Of course I still don't know what it's supposed to do, and there are still a few strange features. (For example, is there supposed to be a difference between `index` and `indRad`, because at the moment they will always be the same value.)

Comment: Thank so so much for your answer! I am so new to Fortran and actually I have another question: why the initial value of v4, v5 and SS will be only 0, which is a number, but we see that in the loop v4, v5 and SS are supposed to be a array, as I understand, because for example: v4 = v4 + array(index). Since as in other programming languages, such as matlab, this line should mean that v4 is also an array, so why the initial of v4 can just be 0? (For the meaning this code, I am editing other's fortran code and this is just part of the beginning.)

Comment: And I have another question, if I want to have another array, say, SS1 and I want SS1 be the first 10 element of SS, so I wrote SS1=SS(1:10), why it shows an error: "Unclassifiable statement at (1)"? ("1" points to SS1.) And I should put this line inside "deallocate(array)" or outside? Thank you!

Comment: Anything declared like this: `REAL, DIMENSION(....) :: a` or `REAL :: a(...)` is an array. In both cases, `a` would be the name of the array, and `a(i)` would refer to the i-th value in that array. So in the above example, `array(index)` would refer to the `index`-th value in the array `array`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also answer my second question?

Comment: Can you help me somehow with this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139376/transforming-part-of-matlab-code-to-fortran90-errors-include-unclassifiable-st